# compare HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> and ArrayList<String> java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` that contains a list of words `Map<String,ArrayList<string>>`
And a list that also contains words  I want to compare this list with the `HashMap`Which gives us another `HashMap`that contains binary values 
1 if word exist 0 if not.
[The problem is it adds the first list to the 2nd ....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoFNT.png)

code is

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> hmm=new                        
HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>(); 
System.out.println("affichage liste:");
for (Entry<String, List<String>> ee : hm.entrySet()) {
String key = ee.getKey();
List<String> values = ee.getValue();
for (String temp : list)
     hmm.add(values.contains(temp) ? "1" : "0");
}
```

Comment: Please post your code in text form, not image form.

Comment: see my answer below .

Comment: I do not understand the process behind comparing `Map<String, List<String>>` to a `List<String>` - by themselves, they are obviously never equal to each other. That are map keys? What are map values? What is inside a list? What is successful comparison? What isn't? Please elaborate your question, it doesn't make any sense to me in its current form.

Comment: @M.Prokhrov here is an example,  Global list["a","b","c"]                   hashmap[1]["a","c"]      [2]["a","b"]  [3]["a","b","c"]   and i want a new hashmap which contains
newhashmap[1]["1","0","1"]      [2]["1","1","0"]  [3]["1","1","1"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compare like below Code:

```
  List<String> global = new ArrayList<String>;
    Map<String,  ArrayList<String>> newMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    Map<String,  ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    for (String key:map.keySet()) {
        List<String> arrayList= map.get(key);
        for (String words:arrayList) {
            List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>;
            for (String globallist:global) {
                if(words.equals(globallist)){
                    newList.add(words);
                }
            }
            newMap.put(key,newList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thnk you but i want compar values in global list with values in hashmap and put the rsult (o,1) in new hashmap

Answer (score 0):

According to your help I found this solution thanks a lot
According to your help I found this solution thanks a lot

```
             HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> hmm=new            
             HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();  
             for (Entry<String, List<String>> ee : hm.entrySet()) {
             String key = ee.getKey();

             List<String> values = ee.getValue();
             List<String> list5=new ArrayList<String>();
             for (String temp : global){

             list5.add(values.contains(temp) ? "1" : "0");


               } 
                hmm.put(key, (ArrayList<String>) list5);




             }'
```